# Paths get messed up whenever I start a new terminal window (OSX)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rvm

I'm very new to terminal, and UNIX command line stuff. I had Rails and Ruby set up nicely with the latest version, and created a new Rails project using the rails new command.

Then I decided to look like a hacker, and use the homegrown skin. After loading up a new window, my ruby -v generated 1.8.7, instead of 1.9.3. Rails is no longer a command.

Here is the PATH for the terminal window that has what I want:

```
PATH=/Users/felix/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin:/Users/felix/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/bin:/Users/felix/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin:/Users/felix/.rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:.
```

I tried looking at those files to see which ones has the path I want. But that lead down this dark and convoluted path that I probably never want to go down again. Are PATH vars supposed to be this long?

This is the PATH for the new terminal window:

```
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/Users/felix/.rvm/bin
```

There are also many other differences when I run env, but I won't go into those details (unless they are required) because I feel like fixing the PATH var would fix the other missing vars as well.

So what can I do to remedy this problem? How do I make these variables stick. Also, is my PATH var comically long? Or is this standard.

Comment: which shell are you using? tcsh or?

Comment: I'm not 100% I understand what you're doing, since opening a new terminal window should basically give you a fresh shell with anything in `~/.bash_profile` executed.  Are you changing the PATH in one window and then expecting that change to persist?  You probably want to add it to your `~/.bash_profile` file.

Comment: echo $SHELL returns /bin/bash.

Comment: I'm using `rvm use 1.9.3` to change the ruby version, and I used `gem install rails` to install rails. Shouldn't those two option changes persist?

Comment: You should use `rvm use --default 1.9.3` (from memory... I switched to rbenv, it's a lot less kludgy).

Answer (score 0):

Nawww, my PATH environment variable is longer than yours.  It sounds like you just need to get accustomed to setting things up in the shell you are using.

Find any article on Google that talks about bash and MacOS, and you'll probably find a bit that talks about .bashrc as well.

Like [this article](http://aplawrence.com/MacOSX/macosxshell.html).

As for making a permanent change to Ruby, I found [this article](http://beginrescueend.com/rubies/default/) which says you can use "`rvm --default use 1.9.3`" and that setting should persist.

Comment: What I meant was is my PATH redundant? For example, what is the difference between these two: `/Users/felix/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin:/Users/felix/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/bin`

Comment: And why is it that `gem install rails` is also non-permanent.

Comment: Hmmm, I just reinstalled rails, and it works now. Now I really wonder why it didn't work last time. What could've happened?

Comment: Gems are installed per ruby version, so when you switch versions with rvm, the gems you installed in one version are not available in the other version.

Comment: Actually, they're installed per gemset.